# In Unity, is UI system much worse in terms of performance than using 2D sprite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm making a card game(such as Hearthstone) with Unity, since there're many texts, I'm using the UI system to make the whole game, meaning each card is an UIImage with an animator on it.

My game is kind of slow when running on old cell phones such as iPhone 6S. I'm not sure if it's caused by not using sprite system with UI texts' transforms attached to the card sprites.

So as the title says, is UI system much worse in terms of performance than using 2D sprite?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general, UI is worse.

This opinion is based on the Unity optimization videos and articles.
where they mention things like:

- When one or more elements change on a Canvas, the whole Canvas has to be re-analyzed to figure out how to optimally draw its elements.. and other similar performance issues (see article link below)

references:

- https://create.unity3d.com/Unity-UI-optimization-tips
- https://youtu.be/_wxitgdx-UI?t=1418 (lots of details about why its slow)

But of course you should use **profiler** your app in device to see whats the actual cause for slow down.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In my case all cards have texts which must be rendered with UI, and these UI's transforms must follow the cards' transforms. So even if I change all cards using 2D sprites, the texts on them will still cost the almost the same. So there's no point changing them into 2D sprites right?

Comment: The UI is only worse if you don't understand how it is optimized. Once you create your UIs in the right way it will be *much* better than sprites.